# Jquery: Textarea in form not serialized

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

Basically I want to open a Modal confirmation to remove an item and ask the reason for doing so in a textarea element. Then, I want to send the value of textarea via ajax to an external file, but the value of it is not going through.

The script (edit_inventory.php). Modal confirmation to the click on #retire button, Modal message confirming and printing what was sent.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
$("#retire").click(function() {
    var ret_data = $("#new_equipment").serialize();
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Remove Item": function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "retire.php",
      data: ret_data,
    }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#ooi").text(''+msg);
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });
    });
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
  });
  </script>
```

The HTML/PHP (edit_inventory.php)

```
if (!empty($eq_id) && $action == "") {
echo '<form name="new_equipment" id="new_equipment" action="edit_inventory.php" method="post">';
echo '<table>';

$status = show ($eq_id);

echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">';
echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button">
<a href="eq_print_label.php?id='.$eq_id.'" class="button">Print Label</a>';

if($status['eq_status']!=3) { //it is !=3
echo ' <div class="button" id="retire">RetireAAA</div>';

echo'
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete this piece of equipment?" style="display: none; ">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
  This item will be removed from the inventory. Are you sure?</p>
  <p>Reason:</p><textarea name="retire_reason" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="150"></textarea>
</div>';

echo '<div id="dialog-message" title="Out of Inventory" style="display: none; ">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    <div id="ooi"></div>
  </p>
</div>';
}
echo'</td></tr>';
echo '</table></form>';
}
```

Function show() echoes the form with all field values gotten from a database. And returns a status (also from the database) !=3 (that's why I see 'RetireeAAA')

Our retiree.php

```
<?php
print_r ($_POST);
//just to test
?>
```

Lastly, retiree.php prints:

```
Array ( [eq_id] => 423A3606 ... [id] => 1111111174 [action] => edit [retire_reason] => )
```

Google Developer's Tool:

```
eq_id:423A3606
...
id:1111111174
action:edit
retire_reason:
```

No matter what I write in retire_reason textarea it passes nothing. The only way to pass something is default a value in editinventory_edit.php and, again, no matter what I write in the textarea, it will pass the value preset by default.

Why is the textarea retire_reason value not serialized or passed?

MORE INFO:
I moved the serialize() line to right before the ajax call. In this case, no element within `<div id="dialog-confirm">` goes through. Furthermore, nothing prints back from the retiree.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the approach and add a new form within the function. Also, I needed to move the serialize to after the form was printed:

```
$("#retire").click(function() {

var idNumber = $("#form_fields").find('.id').val();

$('#form_fields').append('<form name="retire_form" id="retire_form"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+idNumber+'"><input type="hidden" name="retire" value="retire"><textarea name="retire_reason" id="retire_reason" rows="10" cols="30" maxlength="150"></textarea></form>');
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 500,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Remove Item": function() {
    var ret_data = $("#retire_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "retire.php",
      data: ret_data,
    }).done(function( msg ) {
            $("#ooi").text(''+msg);
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                  }
                });
    });
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
});
  });
```

The HTML:

```
if($status['eq_status']!=3) {
echo ' <div class="button" id="retire">RetireAAA</div>';

echo'
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete this piece of equipment?" style="display: none; ">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
  This item will be removed from the inventory. Are you sure?</p>
  <p>Reason:</p><div id="form_fields"><input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="'.$eq_id.'"></div>
</div>';

echo '<div id="dialog-message" title="Out of Inventory" style="display: none; ">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    <div id="ooi"></div>
  </p>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the field name of "retire_reason" to something completely different and remove the other attributes. Try a standard input instead. See if it duplicates whats happening over and over again. This isn't an answer but it should help with debugging.

Comment: I already did what you suggested with no luck :-/ .
Basically it doesn't 'update' the value of whatever is within the <div id="dialog-message"> (if I set a value for any field within that div, it keeps it, even if you delete and write something else)